# Access things outside of module with eval and exec

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, eval

If I import a module that uses `exec` or `eval`, is it possible to give it access to the main program?

myExec.py

```
def myExec(code):
    exec(code)
```

main.py

```
import myExec
def test():
    print("ok")
myExec.myExec("test()")
```

Comment: don't name your file `exec` as you now override the built-in when you import it

Comment: If you change the module name, you will also need to change how the function in it is used in `main.py` — so your last edit was incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

[exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) has a few optional parameters, globals and locals. These basically tell it what global and local variables its allowed to use, in the form of a dictionary. Calling `globals()` or `locals()` functions returns the dictionary with all the global and local variables where you are calling from, so you can use:

myExec.py:

```py
def myExec(code, globals_=None, locals_=None):  # the trailing underscore is so that there are no name conflicts
    exec(code, globals_, locals_)
```

main.py:

```py
import myExec
def test():
    print("ok")
myExec.myExec("test()", globals())
```